# JSON liquid mapping using payload

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to access the the below JSON payload :

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "ApplicantContactDetail": [
>       {
>         "ApplicantBaseDetails": {
>           "CATEGORY": "P",
>           "ULN": "1265847478"
>         }    }
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```

and need output as

> {
>         "Number":2,
>         "Data":
>         {
>             "ResidencyCode":"CATEGORY"
>         }
>       }

i need to map CATEGORY in the output from liquid template, may i know the correct syntax for this to achieve.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you having a specific problem we can help with?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply, i was struggling for the syntax, finally i got the syntax: i used something like this comprising of json paths and it worked:
 "{{content[0].ApplicantContactDetail[0].ApplicantBaseDetails.CATEGORY}}"